# Cannot load grunt/sauce_browsers.yml on grunt dist with Bootstrap 4 Alpha 2

Tags: ruby, bash, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I'm trying to compile a custom version of bootstrap v4 alpha2 but I keep getting 2 errors. Please help. I'm a noob at ruby.

I managed to install

```
$ gem install bundler
```

In fact, there is no .bundle directory under bootstrap

Running the following fails, from /node_modules/bootstrap

```
$ bundle install
```

The following also fails:

```
$ grunt dist


Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Unable to read "grunt/sauce_browsers.yml" file (Error code: ENOENT).
Warning: Task "dist" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: I had the same issue. I solved it by deleting the bootstrap folder in `node_modules` and replacing it with a git clone of `https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev`. Then a cd into the folder and `npm install`, `grunt dist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@neilsimp1 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321360/cannot-load-grunt-sauce-browsers-yml-on-grunt-dist-with-bootstrap-4-alpha-2#comment62273648_34321360) a solution seems to be to delete the `bootstrap` folder in `node_modules`, do a clone of the branch and install Bootstrap there:

```
# 1. Delete the bootstrap directory
cd node_modules
rm -rf bootstrap

# 2. Clone the repo
git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap --depth 1

# 3. Switch to v4
cd bootstrap
git checkout v4-dev

# 4. Install and build
npm install
grunt dist
```

(lines starting with `#` are comments)